# Can we add nomenclature to the list of off topic questions in the help center?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, help-center

This idea has come due to some thinking after I asked a naming convention question that was closed as off topic. I have come to agree with this, and have even found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203880/what-is-the-appropriate-preferred-method-for-questions-concerning-programming) StackExchange question on the matter.

However, the reason I was so torn about it at first was because I can't find anything [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) that states a nomenclature question is off topic, except for the fact that you could argue it is *not a programming problem*.

I do not think that a question of this manner is very common, so I am not proposing we add a new close vote option. I would like to see it added [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), in the list of questions users should avoid asking. To quote:

> To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed,
>   avoid asking subjective questions where …
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”
> - your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more    answers: “I use ______ for ______, what do you use?”
> - there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people    feel like I do.”
> - you are asking an open-ended, hypothetical question: “What if ______    happened?”
> - your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”

Perhaps we could add an additional bullet:

> - your question is about programming nomenclature: "What is the name of ___?"

While this is a small adjustment, and effects what may be a really small amount of questions, it would be nice to have an official SO reference to point users to when trying to explain why these questions are wrong.

Comment: I thought only the "on-topic" page could be edited individually, unlike some of the others which are the same for all sites. I might be wrong about that though.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - Many of the "What topics can I ask about here?" pages do include a list of things that are off topic. This could get added to the list titled **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:** on http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic